# conversion of atom feed to rss feed

Tags: xml, rss, atom-feed

i want to convert a XML find having atom feed into rss feed. I used the following method :

```
public void AtomToRss20(string atomFileName, string rssFileName)
    {
        ConvertToRss20(ReadFeed(atomFileName), rssFileName);
    }

    private static void ConvertToRss20(SyndicationFeed feed, string rssFileName)
    {
        Rss20FeedFormatter rss2 = new Rss20FeedFormatter(feed);
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(rssFileName);
        rss2.WriteTo(writer);
        // You can also use 
        // feed.SaveAsRss20(writer);           
    }

    private static SyndicationFeed ReadFeed(string fileName)
    {
        StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(fileName);
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
        SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
        return feed;        
    }
```

It executes successfully but when i viewed the file I found that it is incomplete and terminated with missing closing tags. 
Can somebody please tell the problem in this or some other method for the conversion.

Comment: It would help if you show us the file you try to convert + the result.

Comment: @Chinmaya - The title of this question should be generalized around the XmlWriter writing incomplete output.  The conversion of the feed from one type to another is not related to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For performance reasons, many of the `*Writer` classes in .NET buffer their output; that is they do not write straight to the output device but keep some of the data in memory until it hits a threshold size. When you close/dispose the writer, then it knows you are finished with it, and will flush any buffered data to the output.

Here, you create an `XmlWriter` but you are never closing or disposing it, so it probably still has buffered content that is never flushed, hence the incomplete file. You're also leaving expensive resources open for longer than is necessary by not disposing it.

Surround your instantiations of classes implementing `IDisposable` with a `using` block, for example:

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(rssFileName))
{
    rss2.WriteTo(writer);
}
```

This will call the `Dispose` method on the writer at the end of the block, and flush the content. You should also surround the instantiation of `XmlReader` with a `using` block.